# Why are build tools, package repositories and programming languages, all so strongly coupled?

Tags: build-system, package-managers

As the title says, I've been noticing this trend that have been all along the evolution of programming languages. Each one has had a niche build tool and a dedicated package/lib repository system.

Its hard for me to ignore that nearly all of them are:

1. Downloading/uploading archives with certain files and metadata.
2. Extracting/packing/altering some directory structure as per the programming language conventions.
3. Calling the compiler or other tools, CLI etc to do work in the defined steps and tasks.

Although some cater to specific conventions of the programming language, but the major part of the same, repeated functionality is hard to miss.

Maven, npm, cargo, gradle, and the list goes on. How could it be *not so obvious* to see the pattern and how come there are no popular generic solutions or tools for this ? Its it just that programming language creators just don't want to collaborate in this space or there is some historical or technical reason I'm missing ?

In short, why not pack the language specific conventions in a plugin or extension that re-used existing agnostic tools/servers, instead of rolling out one more repository server and one more build tool ?

Note: The question is not about the tools themselves, but the common mechanics involved with "sharing code packages" that are re-invented again and again.

Comment: Questions which lump all kinds of tools or things together won't work well on this site. I think there is a different history and different motivation behind each of these tools. If you want to know, for example, why the Rust community created their own package manager "cargo"  instead of making a plugin for an existing one like npm, then ask **one** question about cargo. Ideally, you ask this question in a Rust forum, not here, I am voting to close this as "needs more focus".

Comment: ... and who says there are no plugins? Try https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=Rust or https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=Node

Comment: @DocBrown I could omit explicitly naming the tools, yet the observed pattern is there. Build automation and package management are integral parts of a SDLC that are common, __irrespective of the choice of programming language and tools__. And the question is about why a common problem (even if partial) does not have any attempts for a common solution, and not about why X programming language uses Y tool. Though I agree this question can be considered asking "reasons for opinions" and you can surely close it if you see fit.

Comment: You did not get my point. Omitting the names of any tools would make your question worse, not better. I said you should ask for each tool **individually**, because you will most probably get for each tool a **different answer**. However, this SE site is not a good one for asking about the history of design decisions of certain tools - tool related forums are a way better place.

Comment: I challenge the premise of the question. `make` is *THE* build system, and completely language-agnostic. Dpkg/`.deb`, RPM, are package management systems that have been around forever, and are completely language-agnostic.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Consider it my lack of enough knowledge of `make` to use it as an example/argument in the question. I find your point on deb/rpm, very correct.

Answer (score 4):

Because package maintenance is one of those tasks that most people *think* is easy - just administrate a bunch of version numbers and associated binary content - but really, really isn't.

To properly handle packages for a programming language requires deep knowledge about the runtime system and usually the implementation of its standard interpreter - knowledge that only someone deeply embedded in the community of users of that language will have. A tool that tried to install Javascript, Java, Python and Go libraries would almost certainly do all of those jobs worse than the dedicated tools - probably badly enough that people wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: The question is not about building an all in one tool, but about re-using some of the existing ones with something that requires a lot less work, like a plugin. For example on repository side, just storing and serving a zip archive plus metadata JSON certainly does not require deep understanding of whats in the content of the files, its up to the plugin to make sense of that.

Comment: @S.D. yes, but that functionality is not complicated to set up. You literally can define a scheme by which all classifying info about an artifact is mangled and you can just host the files. E.g. Maven repositories `<tld>/subpath/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/<artifactId>-<version>.<classifier>`. Done.

Comment: @KilianForth what knowledge of the implementation are you referring to? How to load different kinds of libraries into the runtime?

Comment: @marstato different languages use different runtimes and toolchains (e.g. compilers/interpreters), and even different runtimes within language ecosystems. For example, .NET has at least 4 different target runtimes (each with multiple versions); C# projects may target any combination of them, so NuGet needs to handle .NET packages differently depending on the target framework(s) for a project, affecting the way that those packages are checked, installed, upgraded, etc.   Just a totally different set of problems to be solved compared to something like NPM.

Comment: I think the fallacy here is the assumption that different package managers are solving the same problem for different languages when in fact they aren't.

Comment: @BenCottrell i'm asking because all package managers i have had a closer look at all use a standard API of the runtime to load libraries; i.e. all implementations of the language can load libraries at least via that API (e.g. java class loaders, including files in scripting languages, generating a list of object file paths to pass on to the linker, ...). And knowing how the language is implemented is not important there.

Comment: @marstato That's not at all how NuGet works - NuGet has an awareness of the content of MSBuild files (and different versions/variations of MSBuild files);  it downloads files into a 'packages' folder, modifies those MSBuild files to ensure that the .NET Project is using a compatible version of the library, and ensures the changes are right for the MSBuild version (For example, a .NET Framework library will not work in .NET Core, and different versions of MSBuild expect different XML).   As I said in my previous comment, there are just different problems for different languages.

Comment: @Ben Cottrell Why doesn't only a small set of N programming languages have coupled build tools and package managers and many others just don't (cause you know, not the same set of problems...) ?

Comment: @S.D. I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking, but every different language tends to have its own set of tools which work in different ways,  built and designed by different people with different priorities, different goals, different opinions, at different times to solve different problems, etc.

Comment: @BenCottrell There are tools that boast [multi-language support](https://bazel.build/). The hours put into development of such a tool means, there are common problems in package management and build systems. We cannot straight up deny it.

Comment: @S.D. Sorry, but I'm not interested in having an opinionated discussion about whose tools are better or should be used over others, good day.